# Convert json object into multiple arrays android

Tags: android, arrays, json

I have a json object being downloaded from my server that returns a result in the following format:

```
{"Bookname":["Alive-O","All Write Now ","Bun Go Barr 1","Planet Maths","Small World"],"SubjectName":["Religion","English","Irish","Maths","Science"]}
```

What I want to do is turn that into two different arrays to use on the android device.

Here is the request and the looking for the response within my asynctask

```
        String[] BookName;
        String[] BookSubject;
        try {
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(post);

            HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);


        }
```

Just wondering how I store the above result in the two arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be something like this

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

    // for getting booknames
    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Bookname");
    bookName = new String[jsonArray.length()]
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        bookName[i] = jsonArray.getString(i);
    }

    // for getting subjectnames
    jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("SubjectName");
    bookSubject = new String[jsonArray.length()]
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        bookSubject[i] = jsonArray.getString(i);
    }
```

Hope it will help..!!

Comment: Exactly wanted just looking for syntax. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Given that you chose `JSONObject`, that your JSON is that unusual structure, and that you want to mirror that structure in your Java:

Step #1: Call `getJSONArray()` on `jObject()` twice, to get the two `JSONArray` objects (`Bookname` and `SubjectName`)

Step #2: Allocate each `String[]` to be the proper length (call `length()` on the `JSONArray`)

Step #3: For each `JSONArray`, loop over the array indices (0 to `length()`) and call `getString()` for each index, assigning it to the appropriate index in the associated `String[]`